# how to rewrite code ifElse to java 8 style with Options

Tags: java, if-statement, option-type

I have code like this:

```
Optional<String> priorityName = null;
    Optional<SiiPriorityInfo> siiPriorityInfo = getPriorityInfoById(siiClient, id.priorityId);
    priorityName = getNameBySiiPriorityInfo(siiPriorityInfo);

    if (priorityName.isEmpty() && id.customerId != null) {
        Optional<SiiCustomerInfo> siiCustomerInfo = getCustomerInfoByCustomerId(siiClient, id.customerId);
        if (siiCustomerInfo.isPresent() && siiCustomerInfo.get().getPriorityId() != null) {
            siiPriorityInfo = getPriorityInfoById(siiClient, siiCustomerInfo.get().getPriorityId());
                priorityName = getNameBySiiPriorityInfo(siiPriorityInfo);
        }
    }
```

How to rewrite this part use Optional ifElse?

Comment: You can't, because there are two assignments in the inner condition.

Comment: BTW, never assign `null` to an `Optional` variable. You don't need a third state of being (present and absent; and null).